# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined when using for loop

Tags: javascript, css

Why is this wrong?

```
var ContactInfo = document.getElementById("Contact").children;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ContactInfo[i].style.fontSize = "13px";
}
```

After this code execute, the rest of code in function stops working. This piece of code execute on onload event. I try to debug using Chrome where I get this:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.

The loop works when I replace "i" inside brackets [ i ] with a number. But then I don't get loop.

Comment: That magic number `4` could cause a problem, you want to use the number of children in `Contact` instead. If there are less than 4 then one or more will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you have an undefined variable. More than likely you are attempting to index more children than that node has. Instead use the length of the children list to cap the for loop:

```
var contactInfo = document.getElementById("Contact").children;
for (var i = 0; i < contactInfo.length; i++) {
    contactInfo[i].style.fontSize = "13px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you have more than 4 children? Try:

```
var ContactInfo = document.getElementById("Contact").children;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < ContactInfo.length; i++) {
    ContactInfo[i].style.fontSize = "13px";
}
```

Comment: Your logic works... Just for fun I change code to this i < 3 [I have 4 a tags ] and then I don't get error. I just don't understand JavaScript logic and syntax. Basically I am learning in it by heart.

Comment: @Slit remember that all arrays and months start with 0 in JS. Good luck with your learning.